# How can I use Angular2 PathLocationStrategy in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, angular

In our application we want to deploy an angular2 frontend into a spring boot backend ( into src/main/resources/static ) but get rid of the #'s in the urls and use the angular2 default PathLocationStrategy.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to share how I did it, hope it helps somebody:
(SpringBoot 1.3.3, Angular2.beta15, angular2-seed)

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ErrorPage;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer(){
        return new Angular2PathLocationStrategyCustomizer();
    }

    private static class Angular2PathLocationStrategyCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container){
            container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: jep, just like with the dev express server middleware: [require('connect-history-api-fallback')({index: 'index.html'})]

Comment: We have another base url defined for the spring app like localhost:8080/mybase but this still works

Answer (score 1):

These are the three steps you need to follow:

1. Implement your own TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean and set up the RewriteValve

   ```
     import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;  
     ...
     import org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve; 
     ... 

     @Bean TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
       TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
       factory.setPort(8080);
       factory.addContextValves(new RewriteValve());
       return factory;
     }
   ```
2. Add a rewrite.conf file to the WEB-INF directory of your application and specify the rewrite rules. Here is an example rewrite.conf content, which I'm using in the angular application to take advantage of the angular's PathLocationStrategy (basicly I just redirect everything to the index.html as we just use spring boot to serve the static web content):

   ```
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(bmp|css|gif|htc|html?|ico|jpe?g|js|pdf|png|swf|txt|xml|svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf|map)$
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]
   ```
3. Get rid of the useHash (or set it to false) from your routing declarations:

   ```
     RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
   ```

or

```
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false})
```