# How to reload angular single page subpages and don't lose content

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.0.M2, Angular 1.5.8, Angular UI Router 0.3.1, and Thymeleaf templating.

What I want to do is to remove hash # from my url I want to something like this:

http://localhost:8080/#/contact

look like this

http://localhost:8080/contact

What I did:

1. added to my angular configuration.js file something like this:

   ```
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
   ```
2. added to my userIndex.html head

   base href="/userIndex.html"/>

This userIndex.html contains all js libraries, this is my single page index page it contains imports like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/jquery.min.js}" />
```

and UI router:

```
<div ui-view="" class="ui-container"></div>
```

After this hash # disappear from URL, but!

I open my web page http://localhost:8080/ than click link to for example "/contact" and go to sub page URL look perfect http://localhost:8080/contact no hash and page look like this.

[image]

And that when I press F5 to reload web page http://localhost:8080/contact and than content look like this:

[image]

Starting from http://localhost:8080/ and clicking link to /contact  make everything ok, trying to enter URL http://localhost:8080/contact  present raw html without css, js etc. userIndex.html is not loaded is it possible to load it to sub page like /contact?

This is how my project and template config looks like

[image]

Is any body here who could help me to fix this reload thing? Maybe it is something wrong with my spring boot template config?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two ways is that in the first case you download the userIndex.html file and afterwards angular is intercepting your `location` change on client side to render the `contact` state.

In the second case, you are requesting the `contact` path from the server directly. This is where your viewController configuration comes into play and returns the probably not wanted html instead of the index page which would be required to run your angular app.

For node.js there is a concept called `historyApiFallback` that registers a 404 error handler to return the index.html page (e.g. this express module: https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback). In your case you need to avoid the clash between your registered `viewController`s and the routing names used in the angular app. See this question for a similar case: [How can I use Angular2 PathLocationStrategy in a Spring Boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761019/how-can-i-use-angular2-pathlocationstrategy-in-a-spring-boot-application)

All in all it's not that convenient to use the PathLocationStrategy / html5Mode even if it is essential if you later want to have the possibility to also do server side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure server side routing. So when you removed the hash and you could go to the contact and it worked, but when you refreshed it lost the content because after refreshing the page your server tried to find contact.html and if it find in your case it served only that without the css and other stuff. Depend's on your server you can configure your server to fallback to index.html all the time so when it can not find the requested page. and set base to / otherwise server will go to the root of directory and find the contact.html and serve it to you and it will be raw without css. I hope i could explain it to you. You can search for the url-re-writer for your server.

Comment: Is it possible to archive it in spring configuration or throught Controller?